# Setting input field value through JQuery makes required validation fail on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an input field marked as required, a validation message is shown if the user touches the field but do not provide a value or if the form is submitted. It works great.

If I programatically set a value to the field (using JQuery for instance) the required message is still being shown.
Here is my code

```
<form
    name="myForm"
    novalidate>
    <input
        id="myField"
        name="myField"
        ng-model="myField"
        type="text"
        required />
    <br />
    <div
        ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error"
        ng-if="myForm.myField.$touched || myForm.$submitted">
        <div ng-message="required">Required field</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input
        type="submit"
        value="Send" />
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#myField').val("this is a value");
    });

    var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ngMessages' ]);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
    });
</script>
```

The generated html code for the input field shows the following classes:

```
<input id="myField" name="myField" ng-model="myField" type="text" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched">
```

I would have created a planker or fiddler for this, but I couldn't hook the Angular Messages module on those.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.myForm.myField.$setValidity("required", true);
});
```

Angular 1.3.14